# Amazon Alexa: Is the code available for built in skills?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

while writing custom skills for Alexa using Lambda functions, I was just wondering if there is code available for built in skill sets. 
Does anyone have an idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

**As far as I know the code is not available.**

Also some of the built in skills seem to be able to do things that not all third party apps can do so you may come up short if you are trying to replicate functionality.

If you are just looking for sample code the best place to check out is the Alexa [Github](https://github.com/amzn/alexa-skills-kit-js) samples.  They show you how to do a variety of thing from setting up your Lambda function to interacting with a few different models.